# Python pandas: positional indexers are out of bounds with .iloc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

df.tail() returns:

```
35114   False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 0.0 0.0 False   
35115   False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 0.0 0.0 False   
35116   False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 0.0 0.0 False   
35117   False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 0.0 0.0 False   
35118   False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 False   False   0.0 0.0 0.0 False
```

df.iloc[35118] returns:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

df.iloc[[35118]] returns:

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

df.iloc[[10]] returns:

```
10   False   False   0.0   False   ....
```

Nevermind the .astype(int) that I could be doing, why can't this index via an index that clearly exists?

df.index[-10:] returns:

```
Int64Index([35109, 35110, 35111, 35112, 35113, 35114, 35115, 35116, 35117,
            35118], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: i'll assume that the df's index does not start from 0, hence the error. if u pass df.loc[[35118]] u should get  a result, since it is by label. u can confirm the actual index by using df.index.get_loc(35118) and see if it gives u 35118

Comment: df.index[:5]

`Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')` However: df.index.get_loc(35118) returns `34363` ?!?!

Comment: as i said, it means some operation has reduced the length of the dataframe, probably removed some rows, and that's y u have what u have. if u run df.iloc[[34363]] u should get the row at 35118. some operations or transformations done on the dataframe probably lead to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to access a row using *iloc[n]*, the number (*n*) should be
**less than** the number of rows. In this case you attempt to access
a row passing its **position** (not index value), starting from *0*.

So start with running: `df.index.size` and the number displayed will show how
many rows you have.

Apparently, the row number in your DataFrame is less or equal than
the number you passed (some index values are missing).

On the other hand, you can access a row also with *loc[n]*, this time passing
an index **value**.

So e.g. `df.loc[35118]` will return row with index equal to the value given,
in your case the last row.